# Certificate not appearing on tls-ca-bundle.pem

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, rhel, cacerts

not a certificate expert but have gone through different resources on the internet but couldn't get this to work, so posting here.

I have a cert that I would like to include in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`

OS details:
[image]

Let's say this cert is `xx_exp_2023_11_30.cer`.

So, I have copied it to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and then run

```
update-ca-trust force-enable 
update-ca-trust extract
```

and none of them throw me an error.

as per [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525601/update-ca-trust-extract-not-adding-certificates-to-ca-bundle), I have also done this check

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in xx_exp_2023_11_30.cer | grep --after-context=2 "X509v3 Basic Constraints" | grep "CA:TRUE"
```

but yet I do not see the contents being included in

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
```

i.e. `cat tls-ca-bundle.pem | grep <first few characs of the certfile>` yields nothing. The same grep command yields results for other cert files copied over to

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

I also went through [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/739980/importing-ca-certificate-chain-crt-rhel7), to understand if my cert is the in the right folder (source vs anchor), and since it is in `.cer` format it seems it should be `anchor` folder.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Update 1:
I can see that cert I am trying to add lands up in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt` but not in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`. This is also highlighted in the answer from Jeight [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525601/update-ca-trust-extract-not-adding-certificates-to-ca-bundle). But I do not know why not in the other location and my application (which is trying to connect) fails because of cert chain errors, so probably that is looking at `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`. Why does it end up in one and not in the other? And also, what is the difference between these?

Update 2:
I read that the ones which end up in the openssl subfolder are the ones which are `BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`
But mine is of the format `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`. So, not sure why is it landing up in the openssl subfolder and not in the pem subfolder.

**UPDATE 3**
As asked in the comment, below is the output of

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in xx_exp_2023_11_30.cer
```

I have anonymized some contents with xx (or something or bla bla)

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ser num
        Signature Algorithm: encrytpion
        Issuer: O = XX, CN = TST-XX
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 30 05:46:42 2021 GMT
            Not After : Nov 30 05:46:42 2023 GMT
        Subject: CN = xx.tst2.dom
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    something
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            something:
                0-.%+blabla
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                Something
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:Something

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://address.crl

            Authority Information Access:
                CA Issuers - URI:http://address.crt

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            xxxxx:
                0.0
..+.......
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:dnslist
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ......
```

Comment: The difference between /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/{openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt,pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem} is explained in the last two paragraphs of the section EXTRACTED CONFIGURATION of the man page. AFAICT a cert you put in source/anchors _should_ be trusted for all purposes -- and included in pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem. _Maybe_ p11-kit (now moved to trust) is looking at EKU: does your `openssl x509 -noout -text` display include a pair of lines for `x509v3 Extended Key Usage:` and if so does the second line NOT include `TLS Web Server Authentication`? (But this is not programming or development.)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have updated the question with a section called UPDATE 3, with results of what you asked for. There is a section for TLS Web Server Authentication, towards the end. I hope that provides answer to your question.

Comment: You mean a (small) section for Extended Key Usage _containing_ Web Server Auth (in the value). Okay, that part is valid and shouldn't be a problem. However I see there  are two extensions that OpenSSL apparently couldn't decode -- that _might_ be because they are nonstandard, and it _might_ be because they are encoded wrong. One of those, especially the latter, _might_ be a problem for p11-kit; I don't know and without specific details I can't test. If you have support from RedHat you should be able to open a case with them where no one else can see your so-private data.